# In Perforce, how can I switch between branches like Git?

Tags: git, perforce

all!

With Git, I got two branches called Main and Dev, respectively. If a problem pops up on branch Main, and I'm working on Dev, I can just switch to Main for solving that problem, and then switch back to Dev and continue to do my previous work. However, with Preforce, I have to make a new workspace and download the project form main branch into that work space, then solve the problem.

Can I do the same thing like Git with Perforce?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible with regular Perforce.

Perforce Streams make this possible; see [here](https://www.perforce.com/node/9008). But you'd have to have a Stream depot, which is something your Perforce IT team would need to help with. With a Stream depot, your feature branches would each become one stream and you'd be able to switch between them in one workspace.

Comment: Part of the reason why this isn't possible before Perforce Streams is that in a classical, non-stream Perforce, the depot paths can point to arbitrary, incompatible branches. E.g. the following two paths are probably equivalent/interchangeable: `//depot/foo/Main/src/...` and `//depot/foo/Dev/src/...`. Whereas the following two probably are not: `//depot/foo/Main/src/...` and `//depot/foo/Dev/src/a/b/c/...`. It's not until Perforce Streams that Perforce can actually understand what a "branch" is - until then, any given path is a branch.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a //depot/Main stream and a //depot/Dev stream, and you want to switch your workspace from Main to Dev, you do:

```
p4 switch Dev
```

That's all there is to it -- now the Dev stream is in your workspace and you can work on it.  See this blog post for more on what exactly the "switch" command does:  https://www.perforce.com/blog/150428/p4-switch-switching-it

If you're using a "classic" depot with manually defined client views, there are a few different ways to work in multiple branches:

1. One workspace per branch.
2. Map multiple branches into your one workspace.
3. Switch your existing workspace mapping to point at different branches.

Both (1) and (2) require you to have a copy of each branch on disk -- if you move back and forth between branches frequently, or want to be able to run builds/tests in multiple branches concurrently, this can be useful.  The downside is that you're using more disk space and potentially doing some redundant file transfers.

(3) is essentially what "p4 switch" does; you just need to do the different parts manually if you aren't using streams to manage everything (deal with opened files as appropriate, change client view, sync).